# override RAISE behavior for application-based logging in postgres

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am attempting to create application-based logging in Postgres.  We have a lot of SQL functions, each of which logs at various levels of verbosity, such that a new function that wants to use DEBUG level will get a flood of irrelevant DEBUG messages in the console produced by its dependencies if it has any.

It would be great to have a pattern of the form

```
   raise LEVEL APPLICATION 'Hello %', 'world';
```

or

```
   raise log_app(LEVEL, APPLICATION) 'Hello %', 'world';
```

It's possible to create

```
   log_message(LEVEL, APPLICATION,...)
```

But it has two problems.  First, there is overhead to calling the function and then determining current logging setting. This means, every DEBUG message will incur overhead in production, which it would not with RAISE as it would simply ignore the line.

Second, RAISE can accept mixed type arguments:

```
   RAISE NOTICE '% % %', 'hello', 1, True
```

I am not sure how we would go about a function taking a VARIADIC parameter of mixed type.

Would love some idea for how such a pattern could be implemented!

Answer (score 0):

The database message system is not really designed to be extended that way.

What comes to my mind is to use the `DEBUG1` message level for debug messages:

```
RAISE DEBUG 'Entered myfunc, args are % and %', 'beep', 42;
```

Then you can set `client_min_messages` to `debug1` if you want to to receive these messages on the client, and there will be no noticeable overhead if you disable the messages.